# Spring + Velocity Webapp Resource Loading

Tags: spring, velocity

This was a real pain. I am trying to configure Spring to use Velocity templates for emails we are going to send. Following are not acceptable in my scenario.

1. Jar up the templates and adding it to classpath
2. Putting templates in WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib

I am using Spring 3.1.3 with Tomcat 6.x.

The problem is as many people has come across is the  "org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'emailBody.vm'" issue.

Can someone please list out the correct values to be used in .xml and in .java files assuming template files are in WEB-INF/templates folder. It will be a great help for novice spring developers like me. There are 100s of qns on this but they refer to multiple versions of spring and velocity.

One way I tried was to add a bean in dispatcher.xml as below and refer to it in java file.

```
< bean id="velocityEngine"   class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean" >
            < property name="velocityProperties">
                < props>
                    < prop key="resource.loader">webapp</prop>
                    < prop key="webapp.resource.loader.class">org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader</prop>                
                    < prop key="webapp.resource.loader.path">/WEB-INF/templates/</prop>
                < /props>
            < /property>
< /bean>
```

Java code is like below

```
String body = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "emailBody.vm", map);
```

I also tried to do it programmatically,

```
   velocityEngine.addProperty("resource.loader", "url");
   velocityEngine.setProperty("url.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.URLResourceLoader");
   velocityEngine.setProperty("url.resource.loader.root", "/WEB-INF/templates/");
```

Comment: How are you referencing them?

Comment: @Sotirios I have tried many ways but not sure what is the correct way.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'll update the question

Comment: Unzip your jar and check if the templates are in the root folder or in nested folders. You might have to reference the full path. And the jar should only be in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry Sotirios what .jar are you referring here. As I mentioned, adding templates into a jar is not acceptable under my scenario. I want to let the end users to change the template file according to their requirements and they are not java literate to extract or create jar files.

Comment: Why not put templates into external folder? And if you want to keep templates inside war then you have to put them into classpath and use classpath loader (you can copy them there during build process).

Comment: @Ish I misread completely, sorry. If you want your users to add new templates, then you cannot rely on the resource loader. You need to give the full path of the template to your velocity engine.